# Deletion of link list at given position from reverse

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple question about deletion of node from a linked list in kotlin.

```
data class Node(
    var value: Int,
    var next: Node? = null
) 

fun main() {
    val list = Node(1, Node(2, (Node(3, Node(4)))))

    deleteMyNode(list, 4, true)) // 2->3->4
    deleteMyNode(list, 4, false)) // 1->2->3
}

private fun deleteMyNode(node: Node, position: Int, reverse: Boolean): Node {
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special in deleting node from back. If size of linked list in N, then `deleteMyNode(list, x, true))` is the same as `deleteMyNode(list, N-x+1, false)`. And for deleting `n`th node. Just set `next` of `n-1`th node equal to `n+1`th node. (For n=1, just update the head)

Comment: If this is a homework thing, and you're not allowed to change the ``Node`` class (e.g. to store length info like Arpit's saying) you'll have to write a function that iterates over the list until it finds the last node, and do something like keeping track of how many there are

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.